# Slowness in C#.net windows form resize when form has many dropdownlist controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I made a windows form with many dropdown list which are placed inside a grid(not a datagrid) and when I use anchor=left right top bottom and dock=fill options in all of them, the form resize gets slow on runtime.

What's the problem with dock and anchor options?

Is it a general problem with forms? Is it a general disadvantage of using .net components and windows forms?

I don't have any custom events handled on control resize, so the problem is about the controls Microsoft developed. Should I avoid using dock=fill?

Comment: What type of grid are you using?  A TableLayoutPanel or a DataGridView?

Comment: @KevinMcCormick table layout panel

Comment: Do you have anything in the form's OnPaint override or the form's paint event?

Comment: All of these controls will need to redraw when they move because of the anchor.  Redrawing a lot of controls takes time.  A simple fix is hiding the 'grid' with the form's ResizeBegin event and making it visible again with the ResizeEnd event.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a normal that it consumes your processor as on every resize move `form` forms resize `table layout panel` which forces resize and **reposition** child controls (dropdowns), as there is `anchor` property setuped.

There is a trick to avoid to create a frustration for user when resizing:

Use `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` on `BeginResize()` and `EndResize()` event handlers.

Look here for concrete example:

[Prevent window redraw when resizing c# windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353381/prevent-window-redraw-when-resizing-c-sharp-windows-forms)

Should work for you.

Comment: Actually it is not problem of winform or some layout panel, it's problem of combobox control. It's very slow control, it takes a lot of time on creation and resizing.

Comment: For me this only works when making the form bigger for some reason. When I make it smaller again, the anchor doesn't update.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms drawing performance relies exclusively on CPU processor, single-threaded. This means you will face several performance issues if your form draws pictures, or any other complex/numerous UI elements. So you may want to disable unnecessary redrawing events to optimize the overall performance.

The dirty trick below will give you a huge performance gain by disabling redrawing when resizing occurs in your form. This code below should be placed in your form's class:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    this.SuspendDrawing();
    base.OnResize(e);
    this.ResumeDrawing();
}

protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e)
{
    this.SuspendDrawing();
    base.OnResizeBegin(e);
}

protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResizeEnd(e);
    this.ResumeDrawing();
}

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.SuspendDrawing();
    base.OnClosing(e);
    this.ResumeDrawing();
}
```

And this is the extension method which does all the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Example
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

        private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

        public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control control) => SendMessage(control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

        public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control control)
        {
            SendMessage(control.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
            control.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because functions for these things already exist (see accepted answer), so P/Invoke is unnecessary overkill. Plus, your solution requires inheriting from the control.

Comment: Well, overkill or not, it works, and it has been commonly used to considerably improve responsiveness.

Comment: So have the built-in functions such as `Control.SuspendLayout()`. Your externs are redundant.

Comment: Sorry but you are completely wrong, it has indeed a completely different performance effect, just try it by yourself in a complex WinForms application of yours.

Comment: It indeed is a difference. This is due to the fact that this solution disables redrawing while the layout is updated after the resize. So you don't get the jerky adjusting of all controls even once after the full resize.

Comment: And you can also do it without P/Invoke, by creating and sending a window message like `var msg = Message.Create(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); this.DefWndProc(msg);` harder to pack into an extension method that way though ;-)

Comment: Sorry for bother, p/invoke approach did not work for me (.Net8+ I guess) `.SuspendLayout()/...` worked just fine.