# How to draw images on panels without re-painting?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem: my application needs to draw some images on panels.

I make it on Paint(..) event.

But if I move application window then form and all controls will repaint.

How can I get away from it? 
May be I should change event for paiting? 
I have tried to draw into Load(..) event, but application nothing draw into panels in this way.

Comment: Why is it a bad thing that your interface gets repainted?

Comment: It isn't bad, but my screen flickers

Comment: Set the `DoubleBuffered` property on your form like Tigran says.

Comment: @user1134602, try enabling the double buffering on the form if flickering is the only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only parts used are drawn by the application. Therefore, whenever parts not previously visible are uncovered (by moving that window or windows above it, or resizing, minimizing/maximizing etc.) the missing parts need to be redrawn, which is what you're seeing.

If you cannot just redraw the parts, you can for instance use a bitmap and a `PictureBox` to cache the drawn data so that redrawing the window only requires the bitmap to be transferred to the screen without actually redrawing the contents of the bitmap.

In that case you draw your stuff to the bitmap canvas instead of the form canvas.

Comment: Please, tell me, how should I draw on canvas and set it for PictureBox or Panel?

Comment: Create a `Bitmap`, create a `Graphics` object on that bitmap, draw on it, assign the bitmap to the `PictureBox`. Don't forget to properly dispose the `Graphics` object (best done with a `using` statement).

Comment: 1 thing - how can I create Graphics object for Bitmap?

Comment: @user1134602, the graphics object has static methods for that:  `Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)`

Answer (score 0):

You can not get rid of `Repaint()` as this is fundamental `OS` function.

IMO, you are concerned about flipping after resize. To resolve this, you can do like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763716/slowness-in-c-net-windows-form-resize-when-form-has-many-dropdownlist-controls/8763918#8763918).

You can use `PictureBox`es instead of drawing them and, by the way,  do not forget to enable [double buffering](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx)